# How to align WPF button text centered horizontally?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I have a simple problem that nothing I've found solves. I have a button in a XAML WPF main window (Visual Studio 16.1) and I simply need the text content to center align. On the designer window, it looks fine as seen in the first image. When I run the window (either debug or release), I get the second image (the extra left 
margin showing is just an artifact of cropping).

[image: In Designer]

[image: Running App]

It's as if padding is added. I've have searched at length and tried lots of suggestions which are usually some form of setting Padding or HorizontalContentAlignment in either XAML or in code, but to no avail. Even without any background or border, nothing works. Here is the XAML:

```
                <Button x:Name="btRefresh" Content="Refresh" 
                Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" 
                Click="btRefresh_Click" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Margin="5,0"
                Background="{StaticResource ccButton1}"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor1}"
                BorderThickness="2"
                FontWeight="SemiBold"
                />
```

I also tried editing the default template, but there isn't anything in there that would affect simple alignment. Besides all that, it does align perfectly in the designer, so there's really no other property that needs setting according to all the documentation.

I can't be the only one encountering this, as it's such a basic button.

Thanks for any help!

JCK

Comment: Can you replicate this issue when you create a new project and implement the same button?

Comment: Download and install snoop. You can then take a look at exactly what's going on. That refresh string doesn't just present itself. There'll be a textblock does that and i guess you have a style targets textblock. You could put an explicit textblock in your button and set it's style to x:null.

Answer (score 0):

From what I am seeing, do you have another STYLE defined generically for buttons within your project?  or other Theme applied?  If so, maybe that has a superseding default setting that is causing issue for you?  I don't believe blue background and black border are default?  Hence my detection by you identifying two static resources to colors specific within your project.  it COULD be an underlying STYLE that might be causing a distortion on your needs?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23090031)

Comment: @kkakkurt, yes, but comments can be only so long... and if I need to tack on a track of answers, just edit same... and if I can't see his code and it DOES expose something, does that not hurt others with similar possible issue as a trouble-shooting avenue?

Answer (score 0):

use *VerticalContentAlignment="Center"* and *HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"* properties

```
<Button x:Name="btRefresh" Content="Refresh" 
        Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" 
        Click="btRefresh_Click" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Margin="5,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        Background="{StaticResource ccButton1}"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor1}"
        BorderThickness="2"
        FontWeight="SemiBold"
        />
```

it is not worked means your button will affected by some other style.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses! DRap and Andy were right about a conflicting style, especially Andy in identifying a text block style. I have a app-level text block left margin of 10, so I named that style and applied it to each text block. It would be nice to just alter the button style, similar to the below, which also worked, but I couldn't figure out the syntax for including it there.

```
            <Button x:Name="btRefresh"  
                Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" 
                Click="btRefresh_Click" 
                Style="{DynamicResource ButtonNrml}">
                <Button.Content>
                  <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0" Text="Refresh Data"/>
                  </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
             </Button>
```

But still, if there is a conflicting style, shouldn't it be showing in the designer rather than only at run time?

Thanks again!
JCK